# Where can I find video pixel formats' definitions/characteristics?

Tags: 16.04, video, video-conversion

My web (RealSense 410) 3D video camera has some proprietary formats, e.g. **Z16**, **Y8I**, and **Y12I**.

Where can I find these formats’ parameters - like *image type* (e.g., 16 bits unsigned), *little/big endian*, *is white zero*, etc. - so I can import them as *raw files* in `imagej`?

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it on this [Linux Media Subsystem Documentation site](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/pixfmt.html):

YUV Formats:

- [Y8I](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/pixfmt-y8i.html): This is a grey-scale image with a depth of 8 bits per pixel, but with pixels from 2 sources interleaved. Each pixel is stored in a 16-bit word. E.g. the R200 RealSense camera stores pixel from the left sensor in lower and from the right sensor in the higher 8 bits
- [Y12I](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/pixfmt-y12i.html): This is a grey-scale image with a depth of 12 bits per pixel, but with pixels from 2 sources interleaved and bit-packed. Each pixel is stored in a 24-bit word in the little-endian order. On a little-endian machine these pixels can be deinterlaced using

Depth format [Z16](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/pixfmt-z16.html?highlight=z16): This is a 16-bit format, representing depth data. Each pixel is a distance to the respective point in the image coordinates. Distance unit can vary and has to be negotiated with the device separately. Each pixel is stored in a 16-bit word in the little endian byte order.

Answer (score 0):

As Dimitri said, Z16 is a number encoding depth. In order to turn the Z16 coding into something meaningful, you must multiply it by the device scale. [This example shows how for the specific case of Intel Realsense](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/3473#issuecomment-474637827)